# Como adicionar Library angular em uma aplicação ionic

Tags: angular, ionic, library

Tenho uma lib em angular 7, que funciona normalmente quando eu importo o módulo da library no módulo principal da aplicação do ionic, o problema é que se eu usar o router do ionic pra inserir o component "home" por exemplo. Dentro desse componente home, a lib não é encontrada no modulo. existe alguma injeção no modulo das rotas que eu deva fazer para que o modulo do componente home enxergue os módulos "pais" da aplicação?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema foi resolvido trocando o módulo BrowserModule pelo CommonModule, assim resolvendo o problema que o ionic apontava com dupla dependência do módulo BrowserModule.